# JPA query.getResultList() returning wrong objects?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am doing the query below to test if JPA is retrieving the expected results from the database.

I can't understand why `row instanceof Ativo` is returning false. `row.getClass()` returns `br.meuspila.entity.Ativo`, and the printed object is `br.meuspila.entity.Ativo[ id=1 ]`. The imports of the class are ok, and there is not other class named Ativo inside the same package.

```
// OUTPUT:
INFO:   br.meuspila.entity.Ativo[ id=1 ]  // row
INFO:   false  // row instanceof Ativo?
INFO:   class br.meuspila.entity.Ativo  // row.getClass()
```

---

MyMB class:

```
package br.meuspila.mb;

import br.meuspila.database.JpaUtil;
import br.meuspila.entity.Ativo;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyMB {

    public String teste = "testando, 123";

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of ManagedBean
     */
    public MyMB() {
    }

    public String getTeste() {
        return teste;
    }

    public void setTeste(String teste) {
        this.teste = teste;
    }

    public void actionTeste() {
        EntityManager em = JpaUtil.getInstance().createEntityManager();

        try {
            EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
            t.begin();

            Query query = em.createQuery("select x from Ativo x");
            List result = query.getResultList();

            for (Object row : result) {
                System.out.println(row);
                System.out.println(row instanceof Ativo);
                System.out.println(row.getClass());
            }

            t.commit();

        } finally {
            em.close();
        }        
    }

}
```

---

JpaUtil class:

```
package br.meuspila.database;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public final class JpaUtil {

    private JpaUtil() {
    }

    public static JpaUtil getInstance() {
        return JpaUtilHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class JpaUtilHolder {
        private static final JpaUtil INSTANCE = new JpaUtil();
        private static final EntityManagerFactory EMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MeusPila3_WebPU");
    }

    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return JpaUtilHolder.EMF.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

---

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MeusPila3_WebPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/meuspiladb</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

My project configuration (Web Project):

```
JPA 2.1 - EclipseLink-2.5.0.v20130507-rNA
GlassFish Server 4

NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 (Build 201306052037)
Java: 1.7.0_25; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.25-b01
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_25-b17
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; pt_BR (nb)
```

[image: Project view on NetBeans 7.3.1]

Note: `JpaUtil` class was inside `br.meuspila.database` package.

Comment: I don't see any other reason of it printing `false`, than the usage of wrong class. You need to show us some more code. Probably also the imports.

Comment: Assuming that your import is correct and you don't have some other Ativo class imported - it's most likely some sort of classloader issue.  What JPA implementation are you using, and in what environment?

Comment: Give me a minute... I will post the complete code.

Comment: This is not the *complete* code :) if this is truly a class loading problem, we need to understand how JpaUtil works, that's the most important part. We can see it's a singleton, and incidentally often singletons are correlated with many unexpected bugs :P

Comment: Let's try to determine if this is a classloading issue. Create an `Activo` object after retrieving a row, then compare their classes classloader (either use a debugger or print them out). If the twos are different, then we have a classloading problem and you should better describe your environment (eg is it a webapp? Do you deploy the Activo class definition in two different JARs, like say container lib and app lib?)

Comment: Omg, idk what is happening, now `instanceof` returned true...

I printed the classloaders now, and they are equal:

`System.out.println(row.getClass().getClassLoader());
System.out.println(Ativo.class.getClassLoader());

ClassLoaders:
INFO:   WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
INFO:   WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)`

Comment: @Raffaele - This is very strange because now I tried again and this exception was thrown:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: br.meuspila.entity.Ativo cannot be cast to br.meuspila.entity.Ativo`

instanceof returned false again this time  :'(

And take a look at the classloaders now:
`INFO:   WebappClassLoader (delegate=true)
INFO:   WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)`

Comment: (I tried again using `Ativo ativo = (Ativo)row;`)

Answer (score 2):

Random loaders showing up! I can't help without seeing the whole application - but here you a quick fix: remove the `Ativo` class definition (better the entire beans package) from your `WEB-INF/lib`, and put all of your beans inside an archive in the container lib path (refer to your container doc). This way, thanks to delegation, the bean classes will always be loaded from the same loader.

Again, be sure that no bean class definition is in `WEB-INF` (neither in a JAR nor in a plain .class file). If you use a build tool supporting the following, try to put the beans in a separate project (subproject/module/submodule), make other projects depend on it, and set the dependency scope to *provided* (or the equivalent, ie the classes are needed for compilation and testing but must not be included in the output artifact, war, jar or ear)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you think I should use Eclipse or other IDE instead of Netbeans? I did not change any classloader configuration, I wonder why this is happening...

Comment: The loaders used by an application don't depend on the IDE - the subject is not a fit with a comment, so the best thing you can do to understand this bug is reading about the class loading mechanism and playing with it for a couple of days (if you can). Did you try the fix I suggested, ie removing beans definition from everywhere but the container's lib path (or the classpath)?

Comment: I forgot to say: my Ativo class is not at WEB-INF/lib. But I saw that the compiled classes are going to `WEB-INF\classes`

Comment: At the end I think your first statement about the Singleton was right. That Singleton (JpaUtil) was removed and now everything is working fine. I think the EntityManagerFactory was being created prematurely because of the Singleton... What do you recommend to use in place of Singletons?

Comment: Yeah, I tried many times now, it is working as expected. The problem was the Singleton class. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Singletons are not *a problem*, they are a pattern. The thing is that it's a *dangerous* pattern in Java, because involves static and thus a knowledge of the language semantics and the runtime platform which is absolutely not for beginners. On the other hand, it's one of the simplest pattern to describe, so it's easy to get it and trying to apply it as much as possible - but hey! falling is necessary to learn to walk :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Rafaelle, I think the problem was my singleton class: JpaUtil. Fixed the code by deleting that class.

Maybe if I changed that class the problem would be solved. I was observing it and noticed that I did something (possibly) wrong: in the singleton I tried to create 2 instances inside the internal class (JpaUtilHolder)... Maybe I should remove EMF from that internal class and put it as a not static attribute of the JpaUtil class.

Replaced in MyMB:

```
EntityManager em = JpaUtil.getInstance().createEntityManager();
```

by

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the whole project and the steps necessary to reproduce the bug, so we could actually understand what was wrong and more people may benefit from that :)

Comment: Maybe, but I think the static call to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(...);` in the Singleton class was generating the bug...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Entity´s composite PK was different from the PK of the table.
Fixing the mapping, resolve the issue.